# Find most varied match assignments for a 4-player card game

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms, card-games

I'm a programmer and confronted with a particularly hard (at least for me) problem I couldn't find an answer for. This is not a school task or anything. It is something I need personally. I've invested a lot of time in it already.

## The rules

- There is a fixed number of players $N \in \mathbb{N}$, where $(N \mod 4) = 0$, i.e. $N$ must be a multiple of 4. Let's denote the set of all players as $P = \{1,...N\}$.
- For every match, two players play in a team against another team of two players. So a match consists of 4 distinct players.

## The problem

- Find a set of matches $M$, such that every player plays exactly once with every other player (as a team), and
- do this in such a way that every player plays against every other player *exactly two times*.

The requirement comes from the desire for the *greatest amount of variety* for every player.

## My observations

There are some observations I already made, such as:

- There are exactly $\frac{N(N-1)}{2}$ different pairs (unordered).
- For every match, a player plays with one team mate and against two others, therefore there are $N(N-1)$ face-offs between players. It follows that for a perfect variety, each player has to play against every other exactly two times. I made this into a requirement because of this.
- The number of matches is $|M| = \frac{N(N-1)}{4}$, so half the number of team pairs.

## Already tried

I've done the following so far:

- Implemented a brute-force algorithm. There are too many permutations for even a small input size. This is not feasible.
- Tried to formulate it as a *dynamic programming problem*, but figured that it is not possible. The problem can only be solved globally, and not split into smaller subsets.
- Tried to come up with some deterministic relationsship between player pairs, such that the requested properties follow automatically. I failed so far.

## My questions

- I wonder if it is even possible that every player plays against every other exactly twice. Maybe that's a false assumption. And if so: Why is it not possible? Also, if it is not, what is the best I can still achieve in terms of variety? At the very least, each player should face-off against every other player *at least once*.
- Is there a deterministic procedure that achieves the requirements?

Comment: Such problems are often difficult. You may want to search for "social golfer problem" (including on this site). A somewhat (but not very) related problem: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/176419